# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer: can i have a dynamic location value

Tags: java

right now i have this in my xml file:

```
         <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboardsupervisor" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

and

```
            <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>file:C:/jdbc.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Now , my problem is that i do not know the exact location of this file(jdbc.properties) , as this application will going to run on different computers , in some places its installed in c: ,sometimes may be on f:.. So if i dont know the path of this file , if there is anyway i could find it .

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define the file location as system property, eg -Dprops.file=file:c:/1.properties

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>$props.file</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

or

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${props.file}"/>
```

or you can scan the file system

```
public class ScanningPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
    @Override
       public void setLocation(Resource location) {
       File file = findFile(fileName);  // implement file finder
       super.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(file));
    }
}
```

Comment: in this way , will it find the file , if its in e.g    F:

Comment: No, you will have to indicate the exact location in app launch script, eg java -Dprops.file=file:F:/dir/1.properties -jar main.jar

Comment: but this is my problem , i dont know the location of the file , because the location varies from machine to machine, is there any way i can find the file with the name : jdbc.properties

Comment: You can extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and find you file with File.listRoots + File.listFiles

Comment: thanks , where will i write the code for this file.listRoos + file.ListFiles and how will i update the location of my property "location" in my xml file

Comment: I am able to get the location of my file with this file.listfiles but now how will i update this location in my xml file  here :  <property name="location"> <value>..here..</value>

Comment: added an example of how to extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: thanks for the example , for FileSystemResource  i used this import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource, i have spring-2.5.6.jar and  org.springframework.core.jar in my class path , but still its complaining "The import org.springframework cannot be resolved". Any idea..

Answer (score 2):

```
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("context.properties"));

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"applicationContext.xml"}, false);
applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);
applicationContext.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can let `Spring` find the file in the classpath. The file can exist in different locations on different machines but will be loaded as long as it exists on the classpath.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
      <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks , the file at different machines will also be having different credentials inside it .. ,but the file in classpath will be the same in every case i think,So will placing in classpath hep in this ,or any other way we can do it

Comment: Sounds like you want Spring Profiles. See this [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml)

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to deal with it.

1. Put the file in the project, so that you will have the same relative path all the time.
2. Populate the value during build, i.e. put a placeholder in the value tag, and replace it during build by passing parameters. e.g. If you are using ant to do your build, you can use [`expandproperties`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) task to do it.

Comment: thanks , if you could put some light on ur second solution, it looks like what i am looking for but if u can give small example of PlaceHolder