# Access Spring properties from PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

I want to read in a properties file with my data source connection information and be able to get those values from my `Spring-Datasource.xml` file.  Here is what I have:

### Code

```
Properties prop = properties.load(new FileReader(fileName));
PropertySource myPropertySource = new MyPropertySource(prop);

AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"/applicationContext.xml"},false);
applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(myPropertySource);
System.out.println(applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("database.username"));
applicationContext.refresh();
```

This will display the correct value for `database.username`.

### Spring-Datasource.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

I end up with the following error, it does not seem to find any of the properties.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [Spring-Datasource-dev.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driver'
```

Am I accessing them wrong, or missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: Let's see what your property source is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typos... instead of this:-

```
<property name="username" value="%{database.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="%{database.password}"/>
```

... do this:-

```
<property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then you may have forgotten to define `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:-

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:messages.properties"/>
</bean>
```

If you are trying to load dynamic properties file, you can try this: [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer: can i have a dynamic location value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127070/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-can-i-have-a-dynamic-location-value)

Comment: Used <context:property-placeholder location="${props.file}"/> and passed in file name as variable.  Thanks Limc